# What cannot be an interval of convergence for a power-series?

Tags: calculus

Currently I am stumped by a question on my practice sets.

> All are possibilities that exist for the interval of convergence of any power series except:
>
> A) The series converges at all real values of $x$
>
> B) The series converges only when $x=a$
>
> C) The series converges on some interval centred at $a$
>
> D) The series converges everywhere when $x=0$

Currently, I have ruled out A and C. I am still contemplating between B and D though.

Comment: Are you sure you typed $d$ correctly?  It doesn't make sense as it stands.

Comment: @lulu yes I did. I feel like he meant "converges everywhere BUT x=0". If this was the wording would that be correct?

Comment: As I say, with the current wording, I have no idea what $d$ means.  I also guessed that it meant "converges for all $x$ $\textit {except}$ $0$" and if that's what is meant then $d$ is impossible.  The interval of convergence must be an interval, and the line minus one point is not an interval.